# php7.1-zip installation under Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, module

as the title already explains I need to install the zip module from php 7.1 under Ubuntu 18.04. When every I use the command

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-zip
```

and the follwing output.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.1-zip : Depends: libzip4 (>= 1.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Trying to Install `libzip4` does not work either.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libzip4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libzip4' has no installation candidate
```

Can somebody please try to help. Google does not help with unfortunately either.

Elias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A temporary solution is to just download the package file from trusted source like:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libzip4

Afterwards, install it with

```
dpkg -i libzip4_1.0.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

And the `php7.1-zip` will install gracefully.

Answer (score 20):

Use the official repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
```

then:

```
sudo apt install php7.1-zip
```

Comment: This was the exact issue for me.  The stock install of 18.04.1 didn't include the universe repository.  Spun my wheels on this for a while

Comment: Possibly the cleanest solution. Thank you

Comment: The default installation of Ubuntu server does not bring the "universe" repository activated. Just activate it and run the apt command again.

Comment: No luck. `'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.`. Still getting `E: Package 'libzip4' has no installation candidate`

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the following:

if you are using 64-bit then do:

```
sudo apt-get purge libzip4
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-zip
```

if you are using 32-bit system then:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-zip:i386
```