# Composer Install : the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu-14.04

I want to install composer on the server, but I get an error 
"the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system".
I have tried by typing the command

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-zip
```

but get another error

> E: Unable to locate the php7.1-zip package E: Couldn't find any
>   package by regex 'php7.1-zip'

has anyone ever experienced it?

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51878532/6556397

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php7.1-zip installation under Ubuntu 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731062/php7-1-zip-installation-under-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: you're using Apache or nginx ?

Comment: @G.aziz i'm using apache2

Answer (score 0):

The extension php-zip is missing in your environment you should install it

to check your installed extensions run

```
php -m
```

then if `php-zip` is not there you can add it:

if you are on a **ubuntu** this will install it

```
sudo apt install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt install php7.0-zip
```

then you should `restart the server` to apply the update.

Comment: I tried it but, the installation failed. error message is : E: Unable to locate package php-zip

Comment: which php version are you using ?

Comment: in server when i check in the CLI, php version is 7.1, but when i run php.info in web browser show that php version is 7.0

Comment: Si it's php 7.0 you should install php7.0-zip then

Comment: i updated my answer right now you can install multi php version extensions

Comment: i try it, but still failed to install php-zip, error is : E: Unable to locate package php7.0-zip
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-zip'

Comment: You should update your list of packages 'sudo apt-get update' . After adding a new repository and try again